Function 'position' in Common LISP works strange with 'gensym'
I'm novice in LISP, so I'm sorry in advance for probably non-clever question.
Now it is needed to check if the given symbol is a member of the given list of symbols. Function position works well for most cases, but the problem arises when the symbol is generated by gensym function:
(position '#:G808 (list '#:G808))

I expected 0 as a response for this query, but got nil instead. I suspect that # and : have some special meaning, but item '#:G808 anycase does belong to the list '#:G808 doesn't it?

Nothing to do with POSITION. Try (eq '#:G808 '#:G808). Each use of #: creates a new symbol, even though they have the same name.

@Barmar, thanks for a quick reply. Of course, eq fits much better for comparing, but the list may (and usually does) contain several symbols.

But the point is that position uses eq (actually eql, but they're the same for symbols). So if one fails, so will the other.

You'll need to show us the code, which gives you the list (position '#:G808 (list '#:G808)). Where are the GENSYMs?

@Rainer, thanks for reply. You are right, the symbols are generated by `(gensym)'.

Thanks everybody who try to help, and really help me to understand the core of problem. I realized that 'gensym' gives so called uninterned symbols, which ttreated as different? even with the same counter suffix (the same name).
So, the question: is there a way to convert untinterned symbol genereted by gensym to regular one?

(untested) (intern (symbol-name (gensym))) maybe. Though I suspect this might be an XY problem and you're taking the wrong approach for whatever you're trying to accomplish.

If you look at other answers (mostly about macros) you are going to see usages of gensym that may inform you

GENSYM creates a new symbol each time it's used, so those two uses of #:G808 are actually different symbols with the same name.
Assign it to a variable so you'll have the same symbol in both places.
(let ((sym (gensym)))
  (position sym (list sym)))

Or use a comparison function that just compares the symbol names:
(position '#:G808 (list '#:G808) :test #'string=)


You are right. (gensym) generates different symbols (increasing suffix), but I need each (or some) of them several times, so I save them by let.

@Spectorsky: critically, is is not the increasing suffix which makes them different symbols: that's just to give the human reading the code a hint!

If we evaluate (position '#:G808 (list '#:G808)), then the reader sees #:G808 and creates a new uninterned symbol with the name G808. It later sees another #:G808 and creates another G808. They are not EQ.
CL-USER > (eq '#:G808 '#:G808)
NIL

Uninterned means, that the symbols are not interned in a package.
CL-USER > (symbol-package '#:G808)
NIL

CL-USER > (position '#:G808 (list 'G808 '#:G808)
                    :test (lambda (a b)
                            (and (null (symbol-package a))
                                 (null (symbol-package b))
                                 (string= (symbol-name a)
                                          (symbol-name b)))))
1


Every time the reader sees #: it creates a new symbol which is not eq and hence not eql to any other symbol.
Thus for something like (position '#:x '(#:x)) there are two distinct symbols whose name happens to be the same, and the first one indeed does not occur in the list.
(You can think of position as being implemented in terms of eql:
(defun pos (o l)
  (labels ((ploop (lt n)
             (cond
               ((null lt) nil)
               ((eql o (first lt)) n)
               (t (ploop (rest lt) (1+ n))))))
    (ploop l 0)))

)
Note that symbol equality is not string equality: symbols are objects which are more than their names.
Compare this code:
(let ((s '#:x))
  (position s (list s)))

Now there is only one symbol, and it indeed is in the list.
Rather than using gensym a way to reduce this to its bare bones is to use make-symbol, which makes a new symbol with a specified name.  Every such symbol is unique and is not eq to any other symbol.  You can think of the reader macro for #: as implemented in terms of make-symbol.
Things are made harder to see because the printer, by default, does not keep track of which object is which.  So (print '(position '#:x '(#:x))) will print the two symbols the same, even though they are not the same object.  Worse, it will print
(let ((s '#:x))
  `(position ',s '(,s)))

in the same way, even though the symbols now are the same.
You can avoid this by making the printer keep track of object identity when printing, which you do by making *print-circle* be true.  With *print-circle* true the two examples above might print as
(position '#:x '(#:x))

and
(position '#1=#:x '(#1#))

which tells you that, in the second case, the two symbols are the same object.

The simplest solution (I could find) seems to convert uninterned symbols like #:G800 to string by (string s), then obtained strings can be compared by string-equal and searched in the given list by `position'.

Even thought that works, you are not taking advantages of symbols, this is like using strings; in fact, maybe you just need strings in your case?
